# What files can the Xfce4 desktop environment run?

Tags: filesystem, xfce

I haven't had any issues with the file manager or anything, I just want to know if Xfce4 runs pdf or docx files. Or does it run both?

Comment: XFCE is just a Desktop Environment just like GNOME/Unity/KDE. Opening file type depends on the application just like any other OS like Windows, MacOS or even Android. I assume by "runs" you mean opening/viewing those files.

Comment: Yeah. This stupid question is incredibly stupid. I could have figured this out for myself on XFCE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XFCE is just a Desktop Environment just like GNOME/Unity/KDE. File type depends on the how the data has been stored in the file. Applications such as Evince/Adobe Reader are able to handle PDFs because of the way data was stored in the given file not just because the extension was PDF. Therefore, opening file type depends on the application you are using to open that file. For example, Evince can't handle PNG and Shotwell can't handle PDF. This thing is OS independent.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, both.  You can use the same applications that you would with Gnome or KDE.  Use Libre Office, for example.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the information. Now I can look at the code I typed out without getting online!